# AMP HTML file can't render because https://cdn.ampproject.org/robots.txt set to disallow

Tags: javascript, robots.txt, amp-html

Fetch and render my AMP HTML files and all, one by one, having the same issue.

The report from Search Console states "Googlebot couldn't get all resources for this page. Here's a list:"

URL: https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js
Type: Script
Reason: Blocked
Severity: High
https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js/robots.txt

Is there any way to render those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice. This never used to be the case.

Suggest you raise an issue here so they can resolve: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue

Comment: Done! Let's see. Thanx

Comment: I contact them on https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/1695#issuecomment-177540037

Comment: And it's fixed. Must say those AMP guys are very responsive. Even on a Sunday.

Comment: Like them. Don't like AMP. Unnecessary. People should just make their pages faster rather than deliberately limit themselves with non-standard components provided by a javascript library. But that's a whole other conversation.

Comment: I agree, 100%! And the good thing is if you don't like,  just throw it.